# Filtros no Vue só funcionam com interpolação, não funcionam com v-text. Por que?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Eu sei que para usar um filtro no `Vue`, você pode fazer a chamada da seguinte forma:

```js
Vue.filter('hello', function (input) {
      return "hello, " + input;
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  
  data: {
     name: "Wallace",
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">

    {{ name | hello }}
</div>
```

Ou seja, através da interpolação, é possível chamar um `filter` perfeitamente.

O problema é quando tento usar o `v-text`. Parece que o Vue se comporta diferente nesses casos.

```js
Vue.filter('hello', function (input) {
      return "hello, " + input;
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  
  data: {
     name: "Wallace",
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">

    <span v-text="name | hello"></span>
</div>
```

Notem que ao executar, aparece um erro:

> `hello` is not defined

No caso, eu venho do AngularJS e sei que é possível usar os `filters` tanto com `ng-bind` como com interpolação.

Mas e no caso do `Vue`? Por que não funciona?

Não vi nenhum detalhe na documentação a respeito disso.

Existe alguma forma de driblar esse problema?

Comment: Do guia de migração do Vue 1.x > 2.x: [Filters Outside Text Interpolations (removed)](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Filters-Outside-Text-Interpolations-removed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na [sessão sobre filtros da documentação](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html) fala sobre isso. Mais especificamente na parte que diz:

> Filters are usable in two places: mustache interpolations and v-bind expressions.

Então a solução seria usar mustache mesmo.

Na [documentação do `v-text`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-text) é mencionado:

```
<span v-text="msg"></span>
<!-- same as -->
<span>{{msg}}</span>
```

Então seria só usar a interpolação.
A não ser que você tenha algum motivo para usar `v-text` ao invés da interpolação.

```js
Vue.filter('hello', function (input) {
      return "hello, " + input;
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
     name: "Wallace",
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <span>{{ name | hello }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Onde é o botão para reagir com "sad". Triste o Vue não ter isso, mas obrigado pela informação.

Comment: Curiosidade: `mustache` seria a sintaxe de interpolação? O `{{ }}`?

Comment: Sim... por algum motivo os gringos apelidaram os `{{ }}` de mustache porque saporra parecem bigodes. :D

Comment: Mas cara, não vejo motivo para não usar a interpolação.
Também não vejo motivos para o *core* do vue não aplicar filtros no attr também. hahaha

Comment: Eu gosto de usar o `v-text` para não correr o risco do usuário ver o `{{ }}` e também porque é chato ficar definindo isso no Laravel, kkkkk

Comment: Putz... agora entendi. Faz sentido.
Só como curiosidade, tem o [v-cloak](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak) que ajuda nisso.